# Numpy matrix binarization using only one expression

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a way to binarize numpy N-d array based on the threshold using only one expression. So I have something like this:

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
a = np.random.rand(4, 4)
threshold, upper, lower = 0.5, 1, 0
```

a is now:

```
array([[ 0.02 ,  0.833,  0.778,  0.87 ],
       [ 0.979,  0.799,  0.461,  0.781],
       [ 0.118,  0.64 ,  0.143,  0.945],
       [ 0.522,  0.415,  0.265,  0.774]])
```

Now I can fire these 2 expressions:

```
a[a>threshold] = upper
a[a<=threshold] = lower
```

and achieve what I want:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

But is there a way to do this with just one expression?

Comment: For a general case, if the values are such that the `threshold>upper`, flip the conditional statements i.e., use `a[a<=threshold] = lower` then use `a[a>threshold] = upper`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

We may consider [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(a>threshold, upper, lower)
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 9):

Numpy treats every 1d array as a vector, 2d array as sequence of vectors (matrix) and 3d+ array as a generic tensor. This means when we perform operations, we are performing vector math. So you can just do:

```
>>> a = (a > 0.5).astype(np.int_)
```

For example:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

>>> a = np.random.rand(4, 4)

>>> a
>>> array([[ 0.549,  0.715,  0.603,  0.545],
       [ 0.424,  0.646,  0.438,  0.892],
       [ 0.964,  0.383,  0.792,  0.529],
       [ 0.568,  0.926,  0.071,  0.087]])

>>> a = (a > 0.5).astype(np.int_)  # Where the numpy magic happens.

>>> array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
           [0, 1, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Whats going on here is that you are automatically iterating through every element of every row in the 4x4 matrix and applying a boolean comparison to each element.

If > 0.5 return True, else return False.

Then by calling the **.astype** method and passing **np.int_** as the argument, you're telling numpy to replace all boolean values with their integer representation, in effect binarizing the matrix based on your comparison value.

Comment: Excellent! Most efficient method imo!

Answer (score 4):

A shorter method is to simply multiply the boolean matrix from the condition by 1 or 1.0, depending on the type you want.

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(4,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0.63227032,  0.18262573,  0.21241511,  0.95181594],
       [ 0.79215808,  0.63868395,  0.41706148,  0.9153959 ],
       [ 0.41812268,  0.70905987,  0.54946947,  0.51690887],
       [ 0.83693151,  0.10929998,  0.19219377,  0.82919761]])
>>> (a>0.5)*1
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
>>> (a>0.5)*1.0
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write expression directly, this will return a boolean array, and it can be used simply as an 1-byte unsigned integer ("uint8") array for further calculations:

```
print a > 0.5
```

output

```
[[False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True False  True]
 [False  True False  True]
 [ True False False  True]]
```

In one line and with custom upper/lower values you can write so for example:

```
upper = 10
lower = 3
treshold = 0.5

print lower + (a>treshold) * (upper-lower)
```